# default value from get() method

Tags: python

Unexpected error where get() tries to evaluate the default value, despite the key existing in the dictionary

```
def blackjack(cards):
    values = {"J" : 10, "Q" : 10, "K" : 10}
    aces = cards.count("A")
    cards = [i for i in cards if i != "A"]
    hand = 0
    for card in cards:
        hand += values.get(card, int(card))
    while aces > 0:
        if hand + aces > 11: 
            return hand + aces
        elif hand < 11: hand += 11
        else: hand += 1
        aces -= 1
    return hand

cards = ['J','3']
blackjack(cards)
```

```
   hand += values.get(card, int(card))
                             ^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'J'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int` conversion is done before ever calling get, you can just do it after retrieving the value

```
hand += int(values.get(card, card))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def blackjack(cards):
    values = {"J" : 10, "Q" : 10, "K" : 10}
    aces = cards.count("A")
    cards = [i for i in cards if i != 'A']
    hand = 0
    for card in cards:
        hand += int(values.get(card, card))
    while aces > 0:
        if hand + aces > 11: 
            return hand + aces
        elif hand < 11: hand += 11
        else: hand += 1
        aces -= 1
    return hand

cards = ['J','3']
blackjack(cards) # Output: 13
```

In the previous code snippet, sometimes the value for `card` may not be an integer and will raise an error.

I have fixed the issue in the above code snippet.

Comment: This will throw if `cards` contains `'A'`. (OP's original code avoided that problem by setting `cards = [i for i in cards if i != "A"]`.)

Comment: Oh my bad! I have edited it again, hopefully I haven't done anything else stupid like that.
Again, my apologies.